# Ansible loop through group and reference index

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an inventory file defined as follows:

```
[app]
app1.service.com ansible_host=192.168.1.1
app2.service.com ansible_host=192.168.1.2
app3.service.com ansible_host=192.168.1.3
```

I need to generate multiple configuration files for each of those hosts. The current task looks like this:

```
- name: Create node-specific csync2 config files
  template:
    src: "templates/etc/csync2_node.cfg"
    dest: "/etc/csync2_{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_hostname'] }}.cfg"
    owner: root
    group: root
    backup: no
  with_items: "{{ groups[csync2_cluster_nodes_group] }}"
```

And my template looks like this:

```
nossl * *;
group {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_hostname'] }}
{
        {% for host in groups[csync2_cluster_nodes_group] %}
        {% if host != hostvars[item]['ansible_nodename'] %}
        host ({{ host }});
        {% else %}
        host {{ host }};
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
        include /home;
        exclude *.log;
        exclude *.swp;
        exclude /home/ansible;
        auto younger;
}
```

This works correctly to generate template files like this:

```
group app1
{
        host app1.service.com;
        host (app2.service.com);
        host (app3.service.com);
        key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
        include /home;
        exclude *.log;
        exclude *.swp;
        exclude /home/ansible;
        auto younger;
}
```

The problem is that this configuration is causing race conditions, so I need to chain the configurations. What I mean by this is that I need the app1 configuration file to look similar to

```
group app1
{
        host app1.service.com;
        host (app2.service.com);
        key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
        include /home;
        exclude *.log;
        exclude *.swp;
        exclude /home/ansible;
        auto younger;
}
```

And the app2 config to look like:

```
group app2
{
        host app2.service.com;
        host (app3.service.com);
        key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
        include /home;
        exclude *.log;
        exclude *.swp;
        exclude /home/ansible;
        auto younger;
}
```

And the app3 config to look like:

```
group app3
{
        host app3.service.com;
        host (app1.service.com);
        key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
        include /home;
        exclude *.log;
        exclude *.swp;
        exclude /home/ansible;
        auto younger;
}
```

The best way to do this, so far as I can tell, is to utilize the index of the host within the template. The problem is that I'm not sure what the syntax would be to do so. I would like, in the config file, to do something like (Pseudo code since I don't know the syntax for this)

```
nossl * *;
group {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_hostname'] }}
{
        {% for host in groups[csync2_cluster_nodes_group] %}
          {% if host != hostvars[item]['ansible_nodename'] %}
          {# This "item" isn't the current "host", so check to see if this is the last item in the group #}
            {% if group.last == item %}
              {# this is the last host in the group, so pull the FIRST host from the group #}
              host ({{ hostvars[groups['app'][0]]['ansible_nodename'] }});
            {# OK, this isn't the last host in the group, so pull the NEXT host from the group #}
            {% else %}
              host ({{ hostvars[groups['app'][groups.app.index(host)+1]]['ansible_nodename'] }});
            {% endif %}
          {% else %}
            host {{ host }};
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
        include /home;
        exclude *.log;
        exclude *.swp;
        exclude /home/ansible;
        auto younger;
}
```

I hope I'm explaining the problem clearly enough. I'm sure this is possible to achieve, but I'm just stuck on the proper syntax for achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with after some help from reddit.

```
{# This is our "cycle" of hosts - this way the first host is after the first instance of the last host #}
{% set hosts = groups[csync2_cluster_nodes_group] + groups[csync2_cluster_nodes_group] -%}
{% set current_host_index = hosts.index(hostvars[item].ansible_nodename) -%}
{% if current_host_index < 0 %}{{ fail() }}{% endif %}
{% set next_host = hosts[current_host_index + 1] %}


nossl * *;
group {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_hostname'] }}
{
    host {{ hostvars[hosts[current_host_index]].ansible_nodename }};
    host ({{ hostvars[next_host].ansible_nodename }});
    key /etc/csync2/csync2.key;
    include /home;
    exclude *.log;
    exclude *.swp;
    exclude /home/ansible;
    auto younger;
}
```

Seems to work beautifully.